# Facebook api in javascript: how add the privacy?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, privacy

I want publish a post on my friend's wall via Facebook Api in Javascript, but this code don't run correctly when I insert in "FB.api" the "privacy". Can someone help me?
Thank you.

```
var privacy = {value: 'CUSTOM',  friends: 'SOME_FRIENDS', allow: '{UID}'};
var privacy2 = JSON.stringify(privacy);

FB.api("/{UID}/feed", 'post', {
    message: 'Message',
    privacy: privacy2,
    }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Message sent!');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You don't need to run the JSON through `stringify`. Simply passing a JSON will be enough.

Comment: With only JSON the script doesn't run.
Also writing directly in the "FB.api":
    privacy: {value: 'CUSTOM',  friends: 'SOME_FRIENDS', allow: '{UID}'},

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the privacy JSON to include quotes around your keys as well:

```
var privacy={"value":"CUSTOM", "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", "allow":"{UID}"};

FB.api("/{UID}/feed", 'post', {
    message: 'Message',
    privacy: privacy,
    }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Message sent!');
        }
    }
);
```

However, it appears that you cannot post private messages to another user's wall. From the [privacy settings page on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/privacy-parameter/):

> Note: The privacy parameter only applies for posts to the user's own
>   timeline and is ultimately governed by the privacy ceiling a user has
>   configured for an app. It does not apply to posts made by an app on
>   behalf of a user to another user's timelines or to Pages, events, or
>   groups. In those cases, such posts are viewable by anyone who can see
>   the timeline or content in the group or event.

This appears to be why you are getting an OAuth error.

Comment: I tried also that, but nothing. It returns always "[object Object]"

Comment: Instead of `alert(response.error)` can you do `console.log(response.error)` and look at the JavaScript console and describe what is within the Object? Thks

Comment: it said "Object {message: "(#100) The privacy param cannot be applied when a target is specified.", type: "OAuthException", code: 100}". Do you know what it means?

Comment: @acchiappasogni - Edited to answer regarding the OAuth error.